# subtract two lists from each other and get the lowest answer and its corresponding values

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have two lists of lists and I want to subtract values from each other and get the lowest result as well as the letters each operand corresponds to. For example, I have :

```
lst1 = [['A', 2], ['B', 39], ['C', 75]]
lst2 = [['D', 9], ['D', 10], ['D', 11]]
```

And I want to get the output as `['A', 'D', 7]`, since `9-2 = 7` and it is the smallest result I can get when subtracting any of `lst1` numbers from `lst2`.

Another example:

```
lst1 = [['A', 45], ['B', 39], ['C', 75]]
lst2 = [['D', 9]]
```

The output should be `['B', 'D', 30]`.

Comment: What have you searched for, and what did you find? What have you tried, and how did it fail?

Comment: but `10 - 39 = -29` which is smaller...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `itertools.product` to enumerate all the possible pairings of elements from the lists and generate results using a list comprehension, then use `min` to find the smallest 3rd element:

```
from operator import itemgetter
from itertools import product

lst1 = [['A', 2] , ['B', 39] , ['C', 75]]
lst2 = [['D', 12] , ['E', 10] , ['F', 11], ['G', 9]]

results = [[a[0],b[0],abs(a[1]-b[1])] for a,b in product(lst1,lst2)]
print(results)
result = min(results,key=itemgetter(2))
print(result)
```

Output:

```
[['A', 'D', 10], ['A', 'E', 8], ['A', 'F', 9], ['A', 'G', 7], ['B', 'D', 27], ['B', 'E', 29], ['B', 'F', 28], ['B', 'G', 30], ['C', 'D', 63], ['C', 'E', 65], ['C', 'F', 64], ['C', 'G', 66]]
['A', 'G', 7]
```